# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray' when loading an image, what could be the cause?

Tags: scikit-image, imread

I'm trying to build a convolutional neural network for image classification in Python.
I run my code on CoLab and have loaded my data on Google Drive.

I can see all the files and folders in my google drive from python, but when I try to actually load an image it gives me the error in the title.

I'm using the `skimage.io` package, I'm actually just running a notebook I found on kaggle so the code should run fine, only difference I noticed is that the kaggle user was probably not working on CoLab with his data in GoogleDrive so I think maybe that's the problem, anyway here's my code:

`from skimage.io import imread`

```
img=imread('/content/drive/My Drive/CoLab/Data/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person53_bacteria_255.jpeg')
```

Which gives me the following error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray'

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-12-4a64aebb8504> in <module>()
----> 1 img=imread('/content/drive/My Drive/CoLab/Data/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person53_bacteria_255.jpeg')

4 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skimage/io/_io.py in imread(fname, as_gray, plugin, flatten, **plugin_args)
     59 
     60     with file_or_url_context(fname) as fname:
---> 61         img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
     62 
     63     if not hasattr(img, 'ndim'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py in call_plugin(kind, *args, **kwargs)
    208                                (plugin, kind))
    209 
--> 210     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    211 
    212 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in imread(uri, format, **kwargs)
    221     reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
    222     with reader:
--> 223         return reader.get_data(0)
    224 
    225 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageio/core/format.py in get_data(self, index, **kwargs)
    345             self._checkClosed()
    346             self._BaseReaderWriter_last_index = index
--> 347             im, meta = self._get_data(index, **kwargs)
    348             return Array(im, meta)  # Array tests im and meta
    349 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageio/plugins/gdal.py in _get_data(self, index)
     64             if index != 0:
     65                 raise IndexError("Gdal file contains only one dataset")
---> 66             return self._ds.ReadAsArray(), self._get_meta_data(index)
     67 
     68         def _get_meta_data(self, index):

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ReadAsArray'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback of the error (all the lines), rather than just the last line? If it is very long, you can use gist.github.com or pastebin.com to share it

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply, I uploaded the full traceback as you requested.

Comment: It sounds like your path is wrong, please validate that your path to the image is indeed correct. You can use something like `import os` and `os.path.isfile('/content/drive/My Drive/CoLab/Data/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person53_bacteria_255.jpeg')`

Comment: I realized I could view the names of some of the files in my google drive but I could not preview them, while of some files I could see the preview and apparently I could also load them. So even I guess the images were corrupted although I could see them listed on googledrive even from python. So in the end I guess my path was correct but my files were corrupt. Thank you sir for replying to me.

Answer (score 0):

Frist instead of `My Drive` it should be `MyDrive` (no space).

If it still doesn't work, you can try the following:

````
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/CoLab/Data/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA
img=imread('person53_bacteria_255.jpeg')```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by changing the mode of image from "CMYK" to "RGB" in Photoshop.